# Pegar o valor do ID no DataGridViewe C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

Tenho um `datagridview` e neste grid existe dados associado de uma tabela de banco de dados, então queria pegar somente o **id** do valor que está no `datagridview`, e jogar numa propriedade do tipo int que receba esse valor. Como faço?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui o resultado usando essa linha de código

```
   dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString()
```